# Find a name and sum adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have tried searching, but have come up with very little, probably because I don't really know how to summarize what I am looking for.  I tried using a SumIF and SumIFS, but it was not working.
Basically I have a list of 650+ aircraft that I need to compare monthly hours and cycles by their respective tail number.  I need to show how much they increase or decrease each month.  The problem is that I couldn't get my data sorted in my reports.  So now each tail number is in a different position for each month's column, making it impossible for me to merely perform a sum by row.

I would like to use a formula that will find a specified value (ie tail number) and then subtract the hour value in "February" from the same corresponding value's (tail number) hour value in January.

Is this possible or would I be better off cutting sorting and then repasting?

Comment: Not sure if it is only me but I don't understand your question. Maybe you can provide a screenshot with a few marks. E.g. what is "February"? What exact problem do you have with sorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I answered my own question.  It is a SumIF formula, I was just using it wrong.  But to clarify, I have hours and cycles for each tail number aircraft for every month in 2014 (ie January, February, March, ect..).  I needed to evaluate the difference in hours every month for all the tail numbers.  Thanks for taking the time to look at my question though.